# How to change XNA coordinates directions?

Tags: xna, coordinates, axis

**Usually XNA increases X coordinate to right and Y to down.** Like this:

[image: Exapmple]

But in my project i have 2D map. Drawing tile with bigger Y coodinate below OX looking strange (usually people imagines these tiles above OX).

Yeah i can just use

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Turf.Texture, new Rectangle(Turf.X*32, Turf.Y*32*-1),Color.White);
```

//32 is width and height of tile, also code simplified

But it makes a code harder and uglier. ***Don't XNA have any setting \ variable to make spritebatch counting Y to top?***

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can create your own functions to do it, like:

```
void drawSprite(Texture2D texture, Rectangle rect, Color color)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(/*modifying the given rectangle*/), color);
}
```

Comment: this is bad idea because my draw code already difficult and can't be modificied so easy

Comment: Why would this be a bad idea? It creates the alternate coordinate system separate from your existing code. You could even create the function as an extension of SpriteBatch. This way the complexity is *not* added to yor existing functions. In fact this is I think the only way of doing what you ask. You seem to want your own coordinate system, because reversing the Y axis (which you can accomplish by initializing the spritebatch using a Matrix) would *also* flip your sprites upside down.